# Downloading entire HTML page?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to write a screenscraper and I want to download the main page of a website.

I am not getting the entire HTML code that I see when I view the page's source on a browser. How do I make sure I am loading everything I see when I view the source in a browser?

```
# Required Gems
require 'rubygems' # Loads gems
require "nokogiri" # Nokogiri
require "open-uri" # For Nokogiri
require "chronic" # For time parsing
require "cgi" # For parsing urls
require 'net/http' # For image downloading


URL = URI.parse("http://www.gocrimson.com/landing/index")

hBOList = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL))
```

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri problem. Downloading the page occurs prior to Nokogiri ever seeing the content.

Answer (score 3):

The browser's view of the source won't necessarily match what the requested HTML file itself is, due to Ajax being used to load chunks of pages in after the original, requested, page loads.

You can't use normal methods to retrieve a page's source if it uses JavaScript and Ajax, unless you decode the entire chain of content loads and recreate them in your Ruby code.

Or, you can use a browser that Ruby can talk to, tell it to load the initial page, which will then trigger JavaScript's actions in the browser, the browser will load the additional content, then your code can extract it and do what you want. For that you should look at [Watir](http://watir.com), or one of its derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Does:

```
require 'open-uri'
File.open("page_test.txt","w"){|f| f << open("http://www.gocrimson.com/landing/index").read}
```

copy the whole content of the desired page? If so, Nokogiri drops something somewhere and/or the guys are loading something via JavaScript after page rendering, If not, your parsing code would be interesting.

Comment: No, it does not. It does seem like this page has a lot of its content loaded with javascript. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: The answer to this question would be interesting for me, too ;) (some brwoser-imitating gem maybe?)

Comment: Nokogiri won't "drop something somewhere". It might not like a document if it's malformed and will do some fix-up, but that can be checked using the `errors` method.

Comment: `File.open("page_test.txt","w") {|f| f << open("http://www.gocrimson.com/landing/index").read}` is better written as `File.write("page_test.txt", open("http://www.gocrimson.com/landing/index").read)`

Answer (score 0):

I think some contents are loaded through ajax call on some button click or after some action. If you know the things you want and which action doing this. Then you can see [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) . Mechanize internally uses Nokogiri and it helps in loading pages which require some action.

Answer (score 0):

Hisako and redcup you should try watir as the Tin Man suggested above. Something like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://www.gocrimson.com/landing/index"

puts browser.html
```

Should do what you want.